# Keeping the same Public DNS for an EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I understand, that a static IPv4 addresses would be more expensive for AWS, so it changes every time I restart the instance. But the Public DNS could be static, so I would not have to change the address in all my applications, after restarting the Instance.

Can I statically set the Instances Public DNS to something like "MyChoosenName.eu-west-1-compute.amazonaws.com"?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html

Comment: why don't you attach Elastic IP to instance , 5 EIP per account is free ?

Comment: @KushVyas EIPs are always free, as long as they are attached to a running instance and are the only EIP in the instance.  5 is just the default limit of how many you can allocate per region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible

- Because each public ip address in AWS is binded to DNS, so what you
  are attempting add sub-domain to the
  "eu-west-1-compute.amazonaws.com" which is not possible you are not
  owner of the domain provider.
- The thingh you do is bind the public to some other domain which you own like
  Mychoicename.abc.com like we do for other domain bindings either in
  AWS route53 or other domain providers.

Comment: So I can either use the Elastic IP or my own domain name. I still don't understand why AWS does not always use the same public DNS. Sounds like a missed opportunity to always use the same address for an instance.

Comment: if you are using ec2 instance the publis DNS keeps on changing on every restart, but if launched in VPC and associated the elastic-ip with instance then public DNS will not change for that IP/instance for ex: in vpc it would be
ec2-public-ip.eu.wet1.amazon.com.
It changes in ec2 because each time host restarts its assign new public-ip so DNS changes

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The point that I tried to make, is that aws could also just assign a fixed random string as subdomain. A subdomain independent of the public IP. This would solve the issues caused by the dynamic IP for all my SSH applications. And I was wondering why they do that. Seams like an unnecessary drawback to me.

Comment: @arm when you stop an instance, the hardware that it was running on is released.  When you start it again, new hardware is allocated, the EBS volumes are reattached and the instance starts up.  It will be in the same availability zone, but not necessarily the same rack, room, or floor.  It's not the same physical machine, so a different public IP is not really all that surprising.

Comment: Yes, thats the part I understand. And the instance could still be accessible at the same Public DNS, if AWS would assign a Public DNS which is unique to the Instance. But they don't.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that AWS now allows keeping a static public IP address with a EC2 Windows or Linux instance by associating an Elastic IP address with the instance.

Check out their [webpage](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-associate-static-public-ip/) for how to "allocate and associate an Elastic IP address with your EC2 Windows or Linux instance".

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer @arm.